# Какая история у вашего вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение

Примерно девять лет назад я разрабатывал свой первый проект на Go. Проект был небольшим, а я — юн, горяч и чересчур уверен в себе: «Зачем тратить время на написание скриптов развертки приложения на сервере? Правильно, незачем! Я же не буду ошибаться в трех командах для обновления!»

В один прекрасный вечер, придя домой, я взялся доделывать свое приложение. Закончив очередную версию около полуночи, будучи несколько уставшим (учеба–работа–проект), сделал сборку и начал выкатывать обновление на сервер:

```
...
scp -P … -i … user@host:/path/to/server_folder
ssh ...
```

Зашел на сервер в гостевой профиль, авторизовался привилегированным пользователем. (Между тем, шел первый час ночи). И начал набирать знакомые мне команды:

```
...
cd /path/to/server_folder/my_cool_go_app/
rm -rf . /
```

Почему–то после последней строчки терминал не вернулся к режиму ввода команд, а завис на выполнении удаления текущей директории… «Странно… Черт, да там же пробел после точки!»

[image]

Самое плохое, что это был продуктовый сервер. В общем, в ту ночь я понял, зачем нужно резервное копирование и научился быстро разворачивать сохранения. А еще наконец написал скрипты развертки!

Так у меня появился вопрос: [Как избежать опечатки при выполнении удаления?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1017949/6)

---

К чему я все это? К интересному конкурсу в сообществе! =)

#### Конкурс на лучшую историю, связанную с техническом вопросом

С каждым из нас случалась забавная, грустная или просто запомнившееся нам история, связанная с программированием. На мой взгляд, было бы весело поделиться своими историями друг с другом. Чтобы веселья было еще больше, давайте делиться историями в формате конкурса. Правила конкурса предельно просты:

1. Необходимо задать технический вопрос на основном сайте.
2. Затем опубликовать ответ на Мете (в этом вопросе) с вашей историей, которая связана с заданным на основном сайте вопросом. (Пожалуйста, не забудьте добавить в вашу историю ссылку на вопрос на основном сайте.)

Всё!

Победителями станут три участника, набравшие максимальный суммарный рейтинг: рейтинг вопроса на основном сайте + сумма рейтингов всех ответов к нему (без отрицательных и удаленных) + рейтинг ответа к этому вопросу с историей. Авторы трех лучших вопросов с историями получат памятные призы.

Время проведения конкурса: с 1 по 30 сентября. Итоги будут подведены 10-го октября, чтобы уравнять шансы тех, кто опубликовал свои истории в конце сентября.

**Пожалуйста, поделитесь с сообществом вашей историей!**

Да, чуть не забыл. Если у вас несколько историй, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь делиться всеми. Одна история — один ответ =)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98160/discussion-on-question-by-nicolas-chabanovsky-----).

Comment: В ожидании подведения итогов ^_^

Comment: @iluxa1810 Вроде и так всё ясно. Но зная, что тут в двигле `SO` есть доля абсурда, результат может быть и не предсказуемым.

Answer (score 11):

Несколько лет назад я учился в ВУЗ'е(`<понты>МИФИ если быть точным</понты>`) на вечернем отделении, а днем я работал.

На факультете, где я учился преподавался Си и микроконтроллеры, а на работе я самостоятельно изучал C# для написание небольших утилиток для автоматизации работы => никто особо не следил за качеством моего кода.

За годы обучения языкам без поддержки структурной обработки ошибок у меня вырабатывалось  пренебрежение к `try/catch` и я всячески избегал его использовать.

И вот в один прекрасный момент, когда вложенность if, которые проверяли коды возвратов стало достаточно большой, я начал предчувствовать, что я делаю что-то не так и задал вопрос тут:

[Что использовать правильней: if(), или try-catch?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558472/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-if-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-try-catch)

Comment: Обратите внимание, в ответах представлена только одна точка зрения. С чего бы это?

Comment: @avp, не понял вашего комментария.

Comment: Подобных вопросов раньше было полно. Видимо сторонникам `if` спорить просто надоело

Answer (score 11):

Однажды мне пришлось дорабатывать одну легаси-систему на специфическом диалекте VbScript, которая выгружала XML-ки на файлшару для другой системы (1С бухгалтерии).

Достаточно похожие данные нужно было передать из третьей системы в четвёртую, которые строили обмен на основе передачи json в очередь rabbit mq.

И задача стояла в виде: мы не хотим тратить (значительное) время аналитика на подробный анализ какие данные нужны, потом на написание кода.

Мы точно уверены, что есть старая система, которая выгружает данные с запасом, поэтому просто придумайте простой способ кидать данные из легаси-кода в раббит типа как в карбонкопию ставите почту. Выжпрограммисты, наверняка это сделать будет просто, поэтому на задачу вам выделим пару часов, хватит вам, а <s>проблемы шерифа индейцев не касаются</s> трудозатраты подрядчика на той стороне, где нужно будет парсить xml — это вопрос который не рассматривается. (Я надеюсь, все в курсе, что xml надо проверить на соответствие схеме, которую нужно знать — а кроме того, что эта легаси-система была слабо документирована , xml-ка периодически менялась).

Коллеге, который сидел над легаси-системой куда-то уже отправлял данные в виде `ключ1=значение1;ключ2=значение2;` ну он и предложил что будет по такому же принципу сохранять в базу строку, несколько параметров, одним из которых был xml в форме base64.

Вы ещё не почувствовали подвох? Лично я — нет.

Открыл стэковерфоу чтобы вспомить как [кодировать-декодировать в/из base64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11743160/5752652), запнулся о рефлексию, не особо часто приходится (нагуглил [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/a/737156/5752652)),  на основе быстро накидал тривиальный скетч в linqpad'е:

```
void Main()
{
    var request = ";Id=1;UserId=ADMIN;xml=eG1sX2Jhc2U2NF9oZXJl;";

    var dd = ToDic(request);

    var r = ParseParams<ExportRabbitParams>(dd);
    r.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

protected static T ParseParams<T>(string parameters)
    where T : ExportRabbitParamsBase, new()
{
    return ParseParams<T>(ToDic(parameters));
}

private static T ParseParams<T>(Dictionary<string, string> data)
    where T : ExportRabbitParamsBase, new()
{
    var result = new T();
    foreach (var prop in result.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (data.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
        {
            prop.SetValue(result, data[prop.Name]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private static Dictionary<string, string> ToDic(string parameters)
{
    return parameters.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     .Select(x => x.Split('='))
                     .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
}

public class ExportRabbitParams : ExportRabbitParamsBase
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class ExportRabbitParamsBase
{
    public string Xml => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(this.xml));

    public string xml { get; set; }
}
```

Работает — норм, оставалось ещё полчаса, даже написал пару юнит-тестов, сдал тестировщику.

"Не работает" — говорит. Причем иногда работает, а иногда — нет.

Когда я начал разбирать примеры проваленных тестов, то быстро выяснилось, что примеры содержат == в конце строки, например:

> ;Id=1;UserId=ADMIN;xml=eG1sYmFzZTY0aGVyZQ==;

Полез читать описание, как кодируется base64 (каюсь, ранее бывало пользовался особо не обращая внимания, что там под капотом — оно "просто работало", всегда).

Оказалось, что в base64 могут использоваться не только буквы и цифры, но и некоторые специальные символы, в том числе и мой символ '='.

Оттуда же узнал про существование про [base58](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base58), который безопаснее, т.к. кодируется исключительно в буквенно-цифровой алфавит, а значит можно и в url использовать и не бояться использовать совместно с регулярками и т.п.

В том проекте времени особо уже не было заморачиваться с перекодированием в base58, поэтому подумав решили сделать быстрый фикс: разделителем стало двоеточие вместо символа равно.

С тем релизом много ещё было баек, но это больше байки про менеджеров и управление проектом, а я для себя хорошо запомнил область применимости base64, чего и вам желаю.

А вы какой бы предложили вариант кодирования? Если есть что предложить — можете написать свою версию ответа здесь: [Безопасное кодирование байт в строку типа base64 или base58](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1024398/213987)

Answer (score 9):

Однажды мне понадобилось реализовать сложные матричные вычисления в микроконтроллере. В число задач входили - поиск решения задачи наименьших квадратов, поиск обратной матрицы, поиск определителя, нахождение собственных векторов, вращение пространства и т.п. Поскольку у меня нет достаточного времени и квалификации, чтобы реализовать весь необходимый функционал самому, мне пришлось выбрать библиотеку, которая могла бы всё это сделать.

Библиотека должна быть написана на языке `C`, быть лёгкой как по объёму кода, так и по времени выполнения. Таких библиотек нет. Поэтому я скачал библиотеку [meschach](https://maths.anu.edu.au/research/cma-proceedings/meschach-matrix-computations-c) и довольно долго допиливал её чтобы запустить на микроконтроллере. Пришлось подстраивать директивы препроцессора, настраивать операции с плавающей точкой, выбирать настройки компилятора, но в конце концов она успешно скомпилировалась и прошилась.

Библиотека успешно работала и справлялась со всеми поставленными задачами. Однако оставался один существенный недостаток: размер свободной памяти микроконтроллера подходил к концу. Тогда я стал искать способы сокращения объёма кода. Удалять неиспользуемые файлы? Оптимизатор это сам делает. Как же можно уменьшить объём исполняемого кода библиотеки?

Решение оказалось в использовании строковых литералов. Поскольку библиотека изначально была ориентирована на ПК, а не на микроконтроллеры, то она активно использовала стандартный ввод-вывод. В коде присутствовало значительное количество строковых литералов, которые после компиляции попадали в исполняемый файл. Мне это было абсолютно не нужно. Поэтому я решил очистить библиотеку от строковых литералов.

Так появился вопрос [Как удалить все строковые литералы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/777948/3380)

p.s. @Sergey, хоть я и принял ответ, но всё-таки я очистил все файлы ручками.

Answer (score 8):

Разрабатывал я WCF-сервис и там было распределение данных по двумерным массивам - по одной оси месяца, а по второй годы. При этом за некоторые месяца данных в базе могло и не быть.

База возвращала данные в хронологическом порядке, я преобразовывал их в массив и отправлял на фронт (откуда их ajax'ом запрашивало веб-приложение). Ну а как преобразовывал? Делал пару циклов по году и месяцу, сравнивал с записью в данных и если совпадало, то переходил к следующей записи, если нет, то считал, что нужный месяц пропущен, значит переходил к следующему месяцу, а вот в данных не продвигался. И так до тех пор, пока данные из базе не закончатся.

Ну в принципе смотрится верно. Но в некоторых отчётах оказалось, что год и месяц расположены по осям наоборот, мой алгоритм это учитывал - циклы по месяцам и годам менялись местами. А вот сортировку на базе я проворонил - ведь сортировка уже не соответствовала порядку, по которому заполнялся массив.

Ну и наконец всё же попались данные, на которых этот алгоритм зациклился. К счастью это было на dev-сервере, но всё равно было очень странно. Проявлялось оно так: все 5 сервисов, работающих с разными данными, внезапно переставали отвечать. После чего - неясно - просто внезапно всё перестаёт работать (на самом деле - кто-то открывал соответствующий отчёт). Зайдя на сервер, мы обнаружили, что один из сервисов (этот с ошибкой) значительно жрёт процессор и постепенно выжирает память (там в цикле пустые записи добавлялись в список под каждый месяц) и после его перезапуска всё работоспособно. Впрочем, ошибку в нём ещё пришлось поискать.

Ещё интересный факт - интеграционные тесты были, но именно на эту ситуацию они не натыкались :)

Вот на эту тему я задал вопрос [Как уберечься от зависания сервера из-за зацикливания алгоритма?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1029806/178988)

Comment: История скучновата, а вопрос хороший. `+1`. И вроде вы не уложились в регламент конкурса)

Comment: @doox911, время считается по UTC (а не по московскому), так что вполне уложился - вопрос задан 2019-09-30 21:17:56Z. Впрочем, всё равно тут уже у всех такие рейтинги, что что-то выиграть нереально)))

Comment: Мне история понравилась! Спасибо. Кажется, ц меня что–то подобное с провайдером интернета происходит (МТС): подключаю повторитель к роутеру и сетевой маршрутизатор в доме меня отсоединяет каждый полчаса минуты на две три. Надеюсь ребята из МТС прочитают этот вопрос и исправят ПО маршрутизатора =)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а не побовал на роутер OpenWRT поставить? У меня ipv6 от дом.ру настроить не получалось на tplink - они сказали, что соендинение происходит и тут же разрывается. А как перепрошил, всё отлично работает. Правда, у меня собственный роутер.

Comment: @Qwertiy Последний раз, когда ставил OpenWRT, после обновления прошивки, пришлось обновлять роутер (в смысле, новый покупать)... И мне кажется, из за меня, а не OpenWRT. Так что пока не суюсь =)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я первый раз тоже накосяил - получил роутер с ssh без web-интерфейса, пришлось ставить оригинальную по ssh - получилось. Через год попробовал ещё раз, правда, мне помогали по тимвьюверу (к интернету подключился по wifi через другой роутер, а этот проводом) - почему-то всё оказалось гораздо проще и отлично заработало - прошивка просто поставилась и web-интерфейс был по умолчанию. Теперь не знаю только, как на нём проброс портов по ipv6 настроить - вроде через firewall надо, а не через проброс, но я не понял, как :(

Answer (score 7):

Однажды, я ответил на конкурсный вопрос. Но оказалось, что дав единственный верный ответ и набрав более 2 голосов ты не можешь получить даже половины награды. Данная мини история, скорее всего не выиграет данный конкурс, но хотя бы привлечёт большее внимание и быть может в обозримом будущем с другими не будет случаться подобное.

---

Считаю, что вопрос указанный ниже, является техническим. Так как это баг системы.

Так появился вопрос [Не получил награды за конкурсный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9538/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81).

*Спасибо за просмотр :)*

Comment: Интересная мысль) Думаешь, с метавопросами так тоже можно?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я склонен полагать, что на мете сидят люди, в большей степени заинтересованные в развитии SO.RU и создании прекрасной атмосферы.

Answer (score 1):

Доброе время суток.

Как-то потребовалось сделать хранение изображений в нескольких форматах в `Django` проекте. Простым решением было хранение каждого формата изображения в отдельной записи в таблице, но из-за кол-ва связей, таблиц, используемых в фильтрах, был предложен вариант хранить все форматы изображений (ссылки на них естественно) в одной записи в одном поле (кол-во форматов может быть любым).

Так появился такой вопрос [Написать поле модели/формы для хранения изображения в нескольких форматах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1276695/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85)

Помочь решился @andreymal , но беседа с ним переросла в спор о выборе варианта решения вопроса и какой вариант эффективнее, в котором мы оба заполнили тестовые БД кучей данных, чтобы доказать свою правоту. Было немного даже забавно. Но после той беседы, к @andreymal стал относиться более уважительно.

Вот так и познаем сообщество SO