# Не получил награды за конкурсный вопрос

Tags: дефект, конкурс

Ответил на [конкурсный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1024215). Но не получил никакого вознаграждения. Причём, согласно правилам, я должен был получить их.

Comment: Задал вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/q/1618/399 (только для модераторов).

Comment: @Qwertiy о назначении мне баллов?

Comment: Тоже упомянул. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kqV4.png

Comment: @Qwertiy а базы отдельные?

Comment: Какие ещё базы?

Comment: @Qwertiy данные о пользователях портала и прочие.

Comment: Есть какая-то связь с английским SO, точно не понял. Но вроде всё своё, даже хостинг для картинок.

Comment: А в английской-то версии сказано: _"and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period"_ - т. е. ответ всё равно должен быть опубликован после объявления награды. В русском переводе этот кусок наполовину посеяли, наполовину попортили...

Comment: @Qwertiy не понял. Так ответ опубликован. К чему это?

Comment: Ответ должен быть опубликован после объявления награды, которая вручается. А у тебя он опубликован во время предыдущей и до этой. Старым ответам автонаграда не положена.

Comment: @Qwertiy Дебилизм. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это старый баг (или разночтение в правилах, смотря с какой стороны посмотреть) в системе конкурсов. Из-за него ответ, данный до конкурса и принятый во время конкурса считается «старым» и если автор руками не назначил премию, то она не присуждается.

Об этом написано в описании [привилегии начинать конкурсы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties):

> Если в течение 24 часов с момента окончания конкурса вы никого не наградили, то половина баллов вознаграждения автоматически присуждается ответу с наибольшим количеством голосов *[опубликованному после начала конкурса]*, при условии, что голосов не меньше двух. Если ни один из **новых** ответов не соответствует данным требованиям, награда не достанется никому, а баллы вашей репутации, израсходованные на неё, будут утрачены.

Часть в квадратных скобках отсутсвует в русской версии справки, но упоминается в английской:

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted **answer posted after the bounty start**, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no **new** answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.

Из этого ясно что:

- автоматическое назначение премии относится к ответам, опубликованным после начала конкурса;
- принятие ответа не влияет на результат.

Об этом же говорит [справка по премиям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) (как английский оригинал, так и русский перевод):

> Если в течение 7 дней (и «периода щедрости») ни один ответ не побеждает в конкурсе, половина суммы награды присуждается автору ответа, созданного после объявления о вознаграждении и получившего наибольший рейтинг (более 2 баллов)

### Проблема

Есть [старый ответ на Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56789/bounty-award-after-accepted-answer/91440#91440) от основателя Stack Overflow о том, что принятие влияет на конкурсы, но на практике это не подтверждается.

Тема поднималась на Meta.SE: [Bounty not awarded automatically — bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174070/bounty-not-awarded-automatically-bug). Разработчики уточнили, что авторазрешение конкурса относится только к «новым» ответам, но страницы справки не обновили.

Comment: Так я не понял, я ничего не заработал? А автор отдал баллы в пустоту?

Comment: @doox911 Ага, автор упустил возможность присудить свои баллы. :(

Comment: А зная о баге нельзя мне установить эти баллы?

Comment: @doox911 Боюсь что нет. Я немного запутался, в справке о конкурсах также говорится о «новых» ответах. Так что навряд ли Вам эти баллы присудят. :(

Comment: @doox911, модераторы могут только активный конкурс отменять с возвратом репутации тому, кто его создал.

Comment: Вообщем, я конечно не жалею потраченного времени, но осадок от портала остался.

Answer (score 6):

Хотя стоп, что-то я [запутался](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9540/178988):

> Если конкурс начинается автором вопроса и он отмечает один из ответов верным в течение периода щедрости, а затем этот период заканчивается без явного вручения награды, мы предполагаем, что автор удовлетворен полученным ответом, а награда в полном объеме присуждается автору выбранного ответа.

---

Просто конкурсов было два. Ты опубликовал ответ во время первого конкурса, но к его завершению у ответа было 0 голосов, поэтому он не получил награду. Во время второго конкурса ответ набрал 3 плюса и был принят, но он уже не попадал в категорию созданных после начала конкурса, впрочем, ещё он был принят.

---

[Временная шкала вопроса](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1021151/timeline):

```
2019-09-09 16:16:07Z   голос     начало конкурса       Игорь             50
2019-09-09 16:16:07Z   история   добавлено пояснение   Игорь             Привлечь внимание
2019-09-09 16:16:07Z   история   конкурс начат         Игорь
2019-09-13 14:17:38Z   ответ                           doox911           временная шкала рейтинг: 3 
2019-09-17 18:03:10Z   голос     окончание конкурса    Дух сообщества♦   Closed, non-winning bounty for question Id = 1021151
2019-09-19 20:41:26Z   голос     начало конкурса       Игорь             100
2019-09-19 20:41:26Z   история   добавлено пояснение   Игорь             Привлечь внимание
2019-09-19 20:41:26Z   история   конкурс начат         Игорь
2019-09-27 22:02:05Z   голос     окончание конкурса    Дух сообщества♦   Closed, non-winning bounty for question Id = 1021151
```

[Временная шкала ответа](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1024215/timeline):

```
2019-09-13 14:17:38Z   история   дан ответ             doox911
2019-09-24 15:26:56Z   голос     принят                Игорь    
2019-09-24             голоса    ежедневные итоги      недоступно        За: 3 Против: 0
```

Comment: Это же абсурд. Не)?

Comment: А кнопу наградить, автор нажимал?

Comment: @doox911, я же показал лог - не нажимал. Оба раза решение принято Духом.

Comment: А если человек не знал, как наградить человека? Нет ли явного уведомления о том, человека можно наградить? И если он не знал, можно ли наградить после?

Comment: @doox911, вот правила: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty. Мне пока непонятно, что там с принятием ответа, но по остальным критериям ответ не проходит - я расписал почему.

Comment: Это абсурд! Мне, что надо было удалить ответ и добавить новый?

Comment: @doox911, я ссылки на временные шкалы добавил - тебе тоже должны быть доступны.

Comment: @doox911, вообще, автору надо было нажать кнопочку. Одну ведь он нажал. Но действительно что-то странно...

Comment: Ваш ответ лайкнул. Жаль, что система против здравого смысла.