# Отмечает один из ответов верным в течение периода щедрости

Tags: дефект, поддержка, локализация, конкурс

В [справке по конкурсам](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) есть такая фраза:

> Если конкурс начинается автором вопроса и он отмечает один из ответов верным в течение периода щедрости, а затем этот период заканчивается без явного вручения награды, мы предполагаем, что автор удовлетворен полученным ответом, а награда в полном объеме присуждается автору выбранного ответа.

Здесь имеется в виду именно то, что написано? Надо принять ответ именно в период щедрости или в любое время, пока действовал конкурс? Если первое, то почему?

И ещё не очень понятно, должен ли ответ быть дан после начала конкурса или нет. Насколько я вижу, такого уточнения в тексте нет, значит должно быть неважно?

---

Аналогичный фрагмент из [английской справки](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

---

Связанный вопрос: [Не получил награды за конкурсный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9538/178988)

Answer (score 2):

Это явная ошибка перевода, в [оригинале](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) речь идет о полном периоде конкурса:

> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts **an answer posted during the bounty period**, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

Вообще наверное в каком-то контексте «grace period» можно перевести как «период щедрости», но в контексте проведения конкурсов этот перевод звучит двусмысленно. По-моему, «период отсрочки» или просто «отсрочка» было бы понятнее для всех:

> Конкурс продолжается в течении 7 дней. Минимальная длительность конкурса – 1 день. После окончания конкурса наступает отсрочка длиной в 24 часа, в течение которой можно назначить победителя самостоятельно. Просто нажмите на символ награды рядом с любым ответом, чтобы окончательно присудить вашу награду автору ответа. Выбрать свой ответ нельзя.
>
> Если в течение 7 дней (и отсрочки) ни один ответ не побеждает в конкурсе, половина суммы награды присуждается автору ответа, созданного после объявления о вознаграждении и получившего наибольший рейтинг (более 2 баллов). Если два или более ответа, подходящих под условия награды, имеют одинаковый рейтинг (т.е. в случае «ничьей» по баллам), награду получает первый по времени ответ. Если ни один ответ не подходит под условия награды, она не присуждается никому.
>
> Если конкурс начинается автором вопроса и он отмечает один из ответов верным в течение периода конкурса, а затем этот период заканчивается без явного вручения награды, мы предполагаем, что автор удовлетворен полученным ответом, а награда в полном объеме присуждается автору выбранного ответа.