# Лучшие истории о вопросах на сайте

Tags: обсуждение

Вопрос на Stack Overflow — лишь вершина айсберга. На мой взгляд, даже самому простому вопросу на сайте может предшествовать длинная череда неудачных попыток и мучительных поисков новых решений (а иногда и суровых разговоров с начальством). Например, когда–то я удалил весь продуктовый сервер командой `rm -rf . /*` (опечатался, добавив пробел между `.` и `/`), что послужило причиной вопросу «[Как избежать опечатки при выполнении удаления?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1017949/6)».

В течении сентября участники Stack Overflow на русском [делились](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9469/6) своими историями, которые предшествовали их вопросам на сайте. Огромное спасибо всем, кто принял участие!  По итогам конкурса наибольшее количество голосов (история + вопрос + ответы в вопросе) набрали:

- [iluxa1810: Что использовать правильней: if(), или try-catch?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9490/6)
- [AK: Безопасное кодирование байт в строку типа base64 или base58](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9496/6)
- [maestro: Как удалить все строковые литералы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9486/6)

На мой взгляд, все истории очень интересные, приглашаю всех, кто ещё их не видел, прочитать их. Или даже добавить свою! =)

Публикация о конкурсе на MSE «[What is the story behind your question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334861/274323)»

Пожалуйста, поделитесь вашими мыслями о конкурсе и историях!

Comment: Было бы интересно по всем участникам количество набранных баллов на момент завершения конкурса.

Comment: Подскажите, а происходят получение призов за конкурс? Кто-то со мной связаться должен? Просто, жду не дождусь, когда смогу понтануться перед коллегами кружечкой с символикой SO или футболочкой =) или что там дают за конкурсы?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Да, я написал вам на почту, указанную в вашей учетной записи =)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Благодарю. Я написал вам ответ, где хочу уточнить некоторую инфу=)